# My jquery code won't work on Chrome browser

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a html file that has a combo box with 7 options and 7 buttons also for each option. But it won't work on my chrome browser, I believe that there is something wrong with my code. I don't know why, any help will be appreciated.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myButton1").hide();
$("#myButton2").hide();
$("#myButton3").hide();
$("#myButton4").hide();
$("#myButton5").hide();
$("#myButton6").hide();
$("#myButton7").hide();
    $("#opt1").click(function(){
        $("#myButton1").show();
        $("#myButton1").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#myButton1").click(function(){
            $("#myButton1").hide();            
        });
    });
    $("#opt2").click(function(){
        $("#myButton2").show();
        $("#myButton2").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#myButton2").click(function(){
            $("#myButton2").hide();            
        });
    });
    $("#opt3").click(function(){
        $("#myButton3").show();
        $("#myButton3").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#myButton3").click(function(){
            $("#myButton3").hide();            
        });
    });
    $("#opt4").click(function(){
        $("#myButton4").show();
        $("#myButton4").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#myButton4").click(function(){
            $("#myButton4").hide();            
        });
    });
    $("#opt5").click(function(){
        $("#myButton5").show();
        $("#myButton5").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#myButton5").click(function(){
            $("#myButton5").hide();            
        });
    });
    $("#opt6").click(function(){
        $("#myButton6").show();
        $("#myButton6").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#myButton6").click(function(){
            $("#myButton6").hide();            
        });
    });
    $("#opt7").click(function(){
        $("#myButton7").show();
        $("#myButton7").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#myButton7").click(function(){
            $("#myButton7").hide();            
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option id="opt1">One</option>
    <option id="opt2">Two</option>
    <option id="opt3">Three</option>
    <option id="opt4">Four</option>
    <option id="opt5">Five</option>
    <option id="opt6">Six</option>
    <option id="opt7">Seven</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Click 1" id="myButton1"/>
<input type="button" value="Click 2" id="myButton2"/>
<input type="button" value="Click 3" id="myButton3"/>
<input type="button" value="Click 4" id="myButton4"/>
<input type="button" value="Click 5" id="myButton5"/>
<input type="button" value="Click 6" id="myButton6"/>
<input type="button" value="Click 7" id="myButton7"/>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GqdS7/

Comment: Maybe Chrome is tired to see so much duplication of code ?

Comment: Side remark : Don't do `show()` before `fadeIn(1000)`. I removed the show in my answer so that the fading takes effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your code.

### html code:

```
 <select class="mySelect">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="myButton1">One</option>
    <option value="myButton2">Two</option>
    <option value="myButton3">Three</option>
    <option value="myButton4">Four</option>
    <option value="myButton5">Five</option>
    <option value="myButton6">Six</option>
    <option value="myButton7">Seven</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Click 1" id="myButton1" class="myButton"/>
<input type="button" value="Click 2" id="myButton2" class="myButton"/>
<input type="button" value="Click 3" id="myButton3" class="myButton"/>
<input type="button" value="Click 4" id="myButton4" class="myButton"/>
<input type="button" value="Click 5" id="myButton5" class="myButton"/>
<input type="button" value="Click 6" id="myButton6" class="myButton"/>
<input type="button" value="Click 7" id="myButton7" class="myButton"/>
```

### jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.mySelect').change(function(){
        var thisValue = $(this).val();
        $('#'+thisValue).fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $('.myButton').hide().click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

});
```

[`working demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/GqdS7/6/)

Comment: Please don't only link to your code, give the working code here. Cheating around this rule by styling the link to make it appear as code isn't acceptable.

Comment: sorry about my short answer. @dystroy

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce your whole code to

```
$(function(){
    $("[id^=myButton]").hide().click(function(){
         $(this).hide();            
    });;
    $('#idOfYourSelect').change(function(){
        $('#myButton'+(this.selectedIndex+1)).fadeIn(1000)
    });
});
```

with the added benefit that it will work in all browsers (don't bind on the `click` event of an option of a select, use the `change` event of the select).

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZC36/)

Comment: if i generate buttons randomly then your above code will not be work, because each button has different index whenever i generate them randomly.

Comment: @vipul In that case (which isn't OP's case), just use the value instead of the index. But you already know that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TFvza/).

Basically you can't link a control to an `<option>` tag. Hence your issue.

In your html i've added a value attribute to each of your options as it is cleaner and quicker to access the value instead of stripping the id and getting the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#select_list_id').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'One') {
        // Do something for option "One"
    }
});
```